# How to record flac codec audio via JS/AJAX

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am trying to record audio as flac codec instead of opus codec. How can I do that? I have tried setting codec to flac:

```
let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type: 'audio/ogg; codecs=flac' });
```

I also tried this:

```
var options = {
    audioBitsPerSecond : 32000,
   mimeType: 'audio/ogg; codecs=flac' 
}
var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(audioStream,options);
```

But when audio is recorded and saved, I check properties it say codec is opus.

Answer (score 1):

You can check, if a codec is supported using:

```
MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/ogg;codecs=opus')
```

As far as I know FLAC isn't supported by current browsers. You can convert the recording on client side using [Flac.js](https://github.com/Rillke/flac.js) or you simply convert it on the backend.

Comment: Just a note that browsers sometimes claims they support particular codec, but in reality that may not be true. You can see live test: https://www.sitelint.com/lab/media-recoder-supported-mime-type/